# Hello, I'm making an avatar command. I want the embed to appear and write that the user does not have an avatar. But it doesn't work

Tags: discord.py, bots, avatar

` @commands.command(aliases=['ava', 'аватарка'])
async def avatar(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
if not member:
member = ctx.message.author
userAvatar = member.avatar

```
        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.darker_grey(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=f'Аватар {member}')
        embed.set_image(url=member.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Выполнено {ctx.author}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if member:
        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.darker_grey(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=f'Аватар {member}')
        embed.set_image(url=member.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Выполнено {ctx.author}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you need that member check for.. because everyone who can use a command is already a member on your discord or am I wrong? Maybe this will work for you?:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['ava', 'аватарка'])
async def avatar(self, ctx):

    author = ctx.message.author

    if author.avatar is None:
        await ctx.send('The author has no avatar!')
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.darker_grey(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=f'Аватар {author.name}')
        embed.set_image(url=author.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Выполнено {author.name}',icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```